# dpm set-device-owner not working in redmi note 4

Tags: android, device-policy-manager, device-owner

I am trying to make an application device-admin, for that I'm following [Developing a Device Administration Application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#developing)
And when I try to run below command
`./adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.app/.receiver.AdminReceiver`

it gives SecurityException

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setActiveAdmin(IDevicePolicyManager.java:4278)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:145)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:96)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:343)
```

Can anybody please help to get out of this problem, I have removed all the accounts from mobile. I'm using redmi note 4 mobile

Answer (score 0):

Having active accounts would result in different error, so it's not the case.

Please try to type in full path to receiver's package, e.g. `com.example.app/com.example.app.receiver.AdminReceiver`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried that but no luck,
I came to know one more finding that on Android Lollipop & Marshmallow phone it works, but on Nougat doesn't